# pt - Http Post request error ionic probleme No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic, apache-cordova, ionic3

Estou com problemas na origem de acesso no ionic 3
já habilitei `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` no PHP e no apache `.htaccess` porem o erro continua a persistir, fiz uns testes com a extensão postman e ocorreu tudo bem, apenas no ionic que nao funciona retornando junto o erro `forbidden 403`..
O código no 
 config.xml ..

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://grsoftapp.tk/*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
```

Auth-service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

let apiUrl = 'https://dionemax.tk/api/';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

constructor(public http: Http) {
  console.log('Hello AuthService Provider');
}
postData(credentials, type){

return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
  let headers = new Headers();

  this.http.post(apiUrl+type, JSON.stringify(credentials), {headers: headers}).
  subscribe(res =>{
    resolve(res.json());
  }, (err) =>{
    reject(err);
  });

});
```

}

}

Já tentei usar:

```
headers.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin' , '*');
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT');
headers.append('Accept','application/json');
headers.append('content-type','application/json');
```

e também proxy:

```
{
 "name": "proxy-example",
 "app_id": "",
 "proxies": [
 {
  "path": "/api",
  "proxyUrl": "https://dionemax.tk/api"
}
]
}
```

tentei com meta tag também..

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; img-src * 'self' data:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">
```

E nenhum resultado sempre o mesmo erro, oq estou fazendo errado?

Comment: O que você usou para criar a API ? Porque para resolver esse problema com o CORS, você precisa habilitá-lo na sua API.

Answer (score 1):

Se realmente o cabeçalho está dando acesso total, eu sugiro utilizar o pacote http do ionic e não do angular. Este é um pacote nativo.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http